# File Upload works fine as a form, but as an AJAX query returns 403

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a file upload using AJAX but I get a 403 server response... but when I do the same thing as a non-AJAX request, it works fine. Here is my HTML:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function importFileAJAX() {
        fileData = $('#importfileAJAX').prop('files')[0];
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', fileData);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "testimportfiles.php",
            data: formData,
            processData: false
        }).done(function(xml) {
            alert( $(xml).find('result').text());
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, errorText, exceptionText) {
            alert("Error: " + jqXHR.responseText);
        });
    }
    
</script>
</head>

<body>

    AJAX: <input id="importfileAJAX" type="file" />
    <button onclick="importFileAJAX();">Import Files</button>
    
    <hr />
    
    <form action="testimportfiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Non-AJAX: <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Import Files" name="submit">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

My php file (`testimportfiles.php`) is just this:

```html
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root>");
print("<result>0</result>");
print("</root>");
```

The second method works just fine, but the first method returns a 403 error from the server. Is this a configuration issue with my server, or am I just doing something wrong in my code?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm leaving this question unanswered in case there's a better way, but I've solved my problem using [AjaxFileUpload.js](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js), which mimics an AJAX request by dynamically creating a form and targeting the response to a dynamically-created iFrame. The server response is then copied from the iFrame.

I'm still curious if a true AJAX transaction is possible (i.e., something that doesn't require a browser window or iFrame as a target for the server response), but this will work for me in my current project.

Comment: Have you looked at the requests in your browsers network tab to compare the ajax call to the other form call to look for any differences?

Comment: I also notice your form has enctype set.  The default contentType for an ajax call is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Comment: @Toby are you `authenticating` on `backend` with `cookies` ?

Comment: @Taplar, I'm not seeing any clues in the Network tab; the non-AJAX attempt comes back as HTTP 200 with the type as "Document"; the AJAX attempt comes back as HTTP 403 with the type as "XHR." Everything else is the same.

Comment: @Taplar: Also, I see what you mean about the contentType, but changing it has no affect to either method: non-AJAX still works fine, AJAX returns as 403.

Comment: @Usman, I haven't set or read any cookies. Should I be?

Comment: @TobyRush I mean are you authenticating the request on backend with `cookie` in request header ? is there any authentication on backend ?

Comment: @Usman No, I am not... I wasn't aware that I needed to.

Comment: It's clearly an `authorization issue` as response code `403` simply says The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it

Comment: @Usman Thanks... I'm new to file uploads and didn't realize that I needed to do any authorization. If you have any links to some useful documentation, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: you'll find some useful information [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaEj_qZgiKY)

Comment: @Usman Okay, but the files are on the same server. They're even in the same folder... why would any cross-origin issues come into play? And my php backend requires no cookie-related authorization when I do the POST as a non-AJAX transaction, so I'm not sure why it would need any authorization when doing the same thing via AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, especially JealPaul98 and julekgwa for the answers that worked on their servers... using their code I was able to backtrack and discover that I needed `contentType: false` in my initial AJAX call. So my working importFileAJAX function became:

```js
function importFileAJAX() {
  fileData = $('#importfileAJAX').prop('files')[0];
  formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', fileData);
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "testimportfiles.php",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  }).done(function(xml) {
    alert($(xml).find('result').text());
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, errorText, exceptionText) {
    alert("Error: " + jqXHR.responseText);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try your code, I get the result 0 for both methods so it's definitely something server side (may or may not be permission issues)....but this is what I use to upload files. It can be tweaked how you want it but this is one way to do it. I will work to see if I can get a different method using your code.

`<button type="button" onClick="return uploadFile();">Post Status</button>`

```
function _(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
    // I honestly don't know if these 3 lines of code are 
    //necessary but idk what will happen if I delete them so....
}

function uploadFile() {
    var file = _("filetoupload_id").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file12", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "path/to/upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

**UPDATE** I tried the code below and it also worked on my server......

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    AJAX: <input id="file1" type="file" />
    <button onclick="return importFileAJAX();">Import Files</button>
    <hr />
    <form action="tupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Non-AJAX: <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1">
        <input type="submit" value="Import Files" name="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function _(el) {
            return document.getElementById(el);
        }
        function importFileAJAX() {
            var file = _("file1").files[0];
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("file1", file);
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "tupload.php",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false
            }).done(function(xml) {
                alert( $(xml).find('result').text());
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, errorText, exceptionText) {
                alert("Error: ");
            });
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this out. I tried your code on my server and I'm still getting a forbidden error, so it looks like you're right in that it's something specific to my server. I'll check with my ISP (who is running an Apache server through cPanel) to see about security settings. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to upload locally or on a server and if you're trying with a server who are you hosting with, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: I'm trying to upload on a server. My account is with WestHost (westhost.com).

Comment: Do you have access to your error logs? And I would also recommend contacting WestHost to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at error logs before with no luck (it was just showing the 403 response) and had the message to WestHost when @julekgwa commented and started me on the road to the solution: a missing `contentType: false` in my initial AJAX object. I notice you don't have one in yours, so it must be something specific to my server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your PHP file on the server, Using this function the code works on my side.

```
function importFileAJAX() {
    fileData = $('#importfileAJAX').prop('files')[0];
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "testimportfiles.php",
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    }).done(function (xml) {
        console.log(xml);
       // alert( $(xml).find('result').text());
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, errorText, exceptionText) {
        alert("Error: " + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

Then in your `testimportfiles.php`

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, "dir/to/upload/$file")) {
    echo "Success";
}else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, I tried your code and it worked... and then I started backing up toward my code to see what fixed it and as it turns out my PHP file worked just fine. What I was missing was `contentType: false` in the initial ajax object.